# Check all files in two folders with partial match in name and update one of the folders with the newest from both

Tags: performance, console, batch

Here is the code I am using it works fine; however, it obviously takes forever when there are a lot of files to check.

exact shell is cmd.exe.

I am really just looking to make it more efficient.
Here is my run.bat file:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
setlocal enableextensions

:: date variable
set theDate=%date%-%time%
set theDate=%theDate:/=%
set theDate=%theDate::=.%

set folderDate=%date%
set folderDate=%folderDate:/=%

:: backup files still in folder incase of incident or network error/batch failure 
>nul 2>nul dir /a-d "Oven\Working\*" && mkdir "Oven\Backup\%theDate%" && move "Oven\Working\*.*" "Oven\Backup\%theDate%"

:: FTP to Oven plc and retrieve files to working directory
ftp -s:"ftpCommands\Copy" 000.000.000.000  -  rem Actual IP Address in real script

:: check to see if anything is in the folder before running the rest of the commands.
::>nul 2>nul dir /a-d "Oven\Working\*" && goto runCommands || goto eof

:runCommands
:: delete the oven log.
>nul 2>nul dir /a-d "Oven\Working\*.log" && del "Oven\Working\*.log"

:: Append time stamp to copied files and move to stamped directory
ren "Oven\Working\*.txt" ??????????????????????????????????????????"_%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m".txt

:: checks directory for most recent file and gathers the date information from the stamp on it
for /f "delims=|" %%I in ('DIR "Oven\Working\*.txt" /B /O:D') do set Newest=%%I
ren "Oven\Working\Oven*.jpg" "Oven Temp%Newest:~33,14%.jpg"

:: get files names through for loop in working and stamped for comparison with fc
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('DIR "Oven\Working\*.*" /B /O:D') do (
    if exist "Oven\Stamped\%%f" del "Oven\Working\%%f" 
) 
:: move all leftover files form Working directory to Stamped directory
move "Oven\Working\*.*" "Oven\Stamped\"


powershell "Compress-Archive -Path 'Oven\Stamped\*' -DestinationPath '\\oven\liveupdate\date\Backup\%folderDate%.zip' -force"

:: delete from the oven
:: ftp -s:"ftpCommands\Cleanup" 000.000.000.000

:: move and check each file.

set /a RowID=1
set /a LiveRowID=1
set /a SetupID=1
set /a CheckID=1
set /a LiveID=1
set /a BurdenID=1
set /a BurdenSetID=1

for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir "Oven\Stamped\*.txt" /b') do (
    set fileSetName[!RowID!]=%%G
    set /a RowID+=1
)

:keeplooping1
if !SetupID! == !RowID! goto liveSetup
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('set fileSetName[!SetupID!]') do (
    set paramIndex=%%f
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%a in ('set paramIndex') do set index[1]=%%a
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%a in ('set paramIndex') do set index[2]=%%a
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=_" %%a in ('set paramIndex') do set index[3]=%%a
    for /f "tokens=4 delims=_" %%a in ('set paramIndex') do set index[4]=%%a
    set checkName[!SetupID!]=!index[1]!_!index[2]!_!index[3]!
    set checkTime[!SetupID!]=!index[4]!
    set /a SetupID+=1
    goto keeplooping1
)

:liveSetup
for /f "delims=" %%H in ('dir "\\oven\liveupdate\test\*.txt" /b') do (
    set liveSetName[!LiveRowID!]=%%H
    set /a LiveRowID+=1
)

:keeplooping2
if !LiveID! == !LiveRowID! goto updateFiles
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('set liveSetName[!LiveID!]') do (
    set liveIndex=%%i
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%a in ('set liveIndex') do set live[1]=%%a
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%a in ('set liveIndex') do set live[2]=%%a
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=_" %%a in ('set liveIndex') do set live[3]=%%a
    for /f "tokens=4 delims=_" %%a in ('set liveIndex') do set live[4]=%%a
    set liveName[!LiveID!]=!live[1]!_!live[2]!_!live[3]!
    set liveTime[!LiveID!]=!live[4]!
    set /a LiveID+=1
    goto keeplooping2
)

:updateFiles
if !BurdenID! == !RowID! goto eof
set /a BurdenSetID=1
for /f "tokens=3 delims==" %%B in ('set checkName[!BurdenID!]') do (
    set varstore2="%%B"
    goto checkTimeSetup
)

:checkTimeSetup
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('set checkTime[!BurdenID!]') do (
    set varstore4="%%A"
    set /a BurdenID+=1
    goto nextFiletoCheck
)

:nextFiletoCheck
if !BurdenSetID! == !LiveRowID! goto updateFiles
for /f "tokens=3 delims==" %%C in ('set liveName[!BurdenSetID!]') do (
    set varstore1="%%C"
   goto liveTimeSetup
)

:liveTimeSetup
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%D in ('set liveTime[!BurdenSetID!]') do (
    set varstore3="%%D"
    set  /a BurdenSetID+=1
    goto testFile
)

:testFile
set base1="Oven\Stamped\"
set base4="!varstore2!*.txt"
set base2="\\oven\liveupdate\test\"
set base3="!varstore1!*.txt"

set number1=!varstore4:.txt=!
set number1=!number1:h=!
set number1=!number1:m=!


set number2=!varstore3:.txt=!
set number2=!number2:h=!
set number2=!number2:m=!

:: FC ""!base1!"!base4!" ""!base2!"!base3!" 2>nul 1>nul 
:: if not errorlevel 0 goto checkIfNewerOne

if "!varstore1!" == "!varstore2!" (
    if "!number1!" == "!number2!" (
        del ""!base1!""!varstore2!"""_!varstore4!"
    )
) 
:: goto nextFiletoCheck
::checkIfNewerOne
if "!varstore1!" == "!varstore2!" (
    if !number1! gtr !number2! (
        del ""!base2!""!varstore1!"""_!varstore3!"
        move ""!base1!""!varstore2!"""_!varstore4!" "\\oven\liveupdate\test" 
    ) else (
         del ""!base1!""!varstore2!"""_!varstore4!"
    )
)

move ""!base1!""!varstore2!"""_!varstore4!" "\\oven\liveupdate\test" 
move ""!base1!""*.jpg"" "\\oven\liveupdate\test" 
goto nextFiletoCheck
:eof
:: end script
endlocal
pause
exit /b
```

I am backing up the downloaded from ftp folder

downloading from ftp and saving to the downloaded from ftp folder

saving every filename to an array in both folders (the downloaded from ftp folder and the live update folder)
creating partials of each filename in each and matching the first in the downloaded folder to every file and matching whether the timestamp is newer then going to the next one and doing the same thing.

moving the deleting the older files and moving the newer files.  Also deleting the same files from the original folder (this should not be possible to happen though)

the thing is this takes forever:).  binary might not be the best /bc the files might not match due to the oven being active and the file it is saving to could be different sizes.

NOTE: I am trying to speed this process up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are several freely available scripting languages, including [python](https://www.python.org), that may be a better fit for this use case. Recursive glob()'s usually go pretty fast.

Comment: Seconded. I'd presume that powershell will be much faster as well. The basics / internals of CMD processing are IMHO bat-chit crazy. For instance, there are very *interesting* issues with dates and localization.

Comment: Thank you I will look into moving to another allocation in the mean time I found that part of the file was the day and I may just run it on a "daily basis" against only the daily entries to keep the count down:).  Thank you all.